# sql i want to calc. week based on each month 1st day. and also date week start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

my tabel data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYthf.png)

i want to calculate the week column based on month start date and week start date and end date column. data expection also attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJRVJ.png)

Comment: You need to format your tables correctly. You also need to explain what you have tried.

Comment: please check now i formated it.
i want table 1 and table 2 join and data show as table 1 all record

Comment: please check again my table 1 and table 2 data. table1 have brown color but it can't be in table 2 so i want show that brown line also when we join both table

Comment: Once again, *explain what you have tried* and how your tables are related.

Comment: i have 5records in table1, OCStypeID  and table2 styleid are same. so i want when join both table so query display  5record are show same in table 1

Comment: You have 5 records in table 1 with the same `OCStypeID`, and 4 records in table 2 with the same `StyleID`. If that's the only relationship between your tables, you need to explain why your result table doesn't contain 20 records, matching each record from table 1 with each record from table 2.

Comment: sorry some misstake  **colorname also same but i want if colorname is not exit table2 then also will display table1 colorname**

Comment: Correct your expected results then. It's currently blank.

Comment: yes, please check now my current result

Answer (score 1):

Just LEFT JOIN Table2 to Table1

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.OCStypeID
, t1.OCNum
, t1.ColorName
, t1.Orderqty
, COALESCE(CAST(t2.StyleID AS VARCHAR(30)), '') AS "StyleID"
, COALESCE(t2.ColorName, '') AS "ColorName" 
, COALESCE(t2.Material, '') AS "Material"
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
  ON t2.StyleID = t1.OCStypeID
 AND t2.ColorName = t1.ColorName
```

| OCStypeID | OCNum | ColorName | Orderqty | StyleID | ColorName | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 220009069 | 106307.1 | BLACK | 200 | 220009069 | BLACK | Fabric-(ITL-FC) |
| 220009069 | 106307.1 | BLUE | 200 | 220009069 | BLUE | Fabric-(ITL-FC) |
| 220009069 | 106307.1 | BROWN | 4 |  |  |  |
| 220009069 | 106307.1 | DARK GREEN | 240 | 220009069 | DARK GREEN | Fabric-(ITL-FC) |
| 220009069 | 106307.1 | WHITE | 20 | 220009069 | WHITE | Fabric-(ITL-FC) |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=14e517a22f1991ca34dc0cc9db42afa2)*

Comment: **still brown colorname not coming**

OCStypeID OCNum Colorname Orderqty StyleID StyleColorName Material 220009069 106307.1 BLACK 100 220009069 BLACK Fabric-(ITL-FC) 220009069 106307.1 BLUE 100 220009069 BLUE Fabric-(ITL-FC) 220009069 106307.1 DARK GREEN 6 220009069 DARK GREEN Fabric-(ITL-FC) 220009069 106307.1 WHITE 10 220009069 WHITE Fabric-(ITL-FC)

Comment: Ok, changed it.

Comment: **still ramin same**

Comment: Changed it. Maybe it's an empty string or just a CHAR with only spaces. What kind of database do you use? Not sure if `TRIM` is standard ANSI SQL.

Comment: sql server 2018
**still same**

Comment: Ok, Sql Server doesn't have TRIM. But has LTRIM & RTRIM. See update.

Comment: **tried but result are same**

Comment: Now I doubt that Table1 even has BROWN. It's a LEFT JOIN. So it should at least show t1.ColorName = 'BROWN'.

Comment: its in the table1

Comment: **please check again my table 1 and table 2 data**
table1 have brown color but it can't be in table 2 so i want show that brown line also when we join both table

Comment: See updated solution.

Comment: That's look good, but I need styleid and material also is it possible ?